# Why are the Melpa (Emacs Lisp repository) version numbers so high?

Tags: emacs, elisp, emacs24

I once had [Melpa](http://melpa.milkbox.net/) in my list of elisp repositories; I recently removed it after realizing that its version numbers surely had to be on a completely different scale than those of the other repos (eg [Marmalade](http://marmalade-repo.org/), the normal Elpa)...therefore when using U to "Mark Upgradable Packages", the version of every package that existed in both Melpa and another repository would always be the Melpa version, just because the Melpa repo version #s are ridiculously high.

**Example 1:** *The available Marmalade version of `abl-mode` is **0.9.0**. The available Melpa version of the same package is... **20130607.917**?!*

**Example 2:** *The available Marmalade version of `flex-autopair` is **0.3**. The available Melpa version of the same package is **20120809.2118**... Something's up.*

I wouldn't be concerned if it weren't for the fact that this means that what the Emacs package manager thinks is the most recent version...may not be the most recent version. Since Melpa (which has some awesome packages that other repos don't, btw) is obviously using a different numbering/versioning system... I just can't include it in `package-archives` anymore. Is there some kind of package that fixes this/translates the Melpa version numbers to normal ones and makes Melpa compatible with the other repos?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The version numbers represent the date when each package was pulled from its repository.

[There's an issue on the github page explaining this further.](https://github.com/milkypostman/melpa/issues/250)

It's also possible to exclude certain packages from a specific archive. [Read here to see how](https://github.com/milkypostman/melpa#melpa-package)

I wouldn't worry too much about your emacs being fooled into downloading an old version. The cool thing about Melpa is that (for most packages) it automatically pulls the most recent version of each package from its source repository (typically git). So it's very unlikely a package will be outdated.

Comment: So most people would want to exclude MELPA by default, and only explicitly include it as a source for any package for which they wished to track the repository HEAD, rather than the latest stable release?

Comment: @phils I don't think so. When packages have been put in MELPA the author of that package has decided that master is stable enough to do so. Experimental/unstable changes should be done on topic branches.

Comment: It all depends on how each developer manages his package. Some people use the MASTER branch for development code, while others leave it to other branches. In general though, I use tons of packages from Melpa and don't remember ever having a problem because of unstable code. @phils

Comment: Knowing that a package author was keeping the master branch stable would certainly be a reason to happily use it as a package source, but presumably that requires you to take a look at the repository yourself to ascertain whether this is the case (I'm guessing that Emacs' package manager isn't going to have that kind of information). So if a package is available from multiple sources, one of which has understandable version numbers indicating stability (or otherwise), and one which has a date-stamp which might reference the head of the dev branch, I'm thinking the former is the safer bet.

Comment: Perhaps if authors tagged their releases with a version number (ideally in sync with the versions from other sources), MELPA could use that instead. Some way to distinguish between a tagged stable release and an un-tagged HEAD would probably be very useful.

Comment: @phils (To your previous comment) Yes, that is a safer bet. (To your latest comment) It is my understanding that authors do provide a version number (at least, I know I do). It's a `;;; Version:` line near the top of the file. I'm not entirely sure why Melpa feels obligated to ignore them.

Comment: @BruceConnor That's the funny thing; I downloaded abc-mode.el directly from the Melpa site (eg not through Emacs) and looked at it and the first two lines of the header are:

_;;; abc-mode.el --- Major mode for editing abc music files
;; Version: 20130607.917_

As someone with limited elisp experience I find this confusing. Who would take the time to add a version number like that to the top of the file? I'm guessing that it is automatically added when the file or whatever is added to the repo.

Comment: @AsianSquirrel yes, Melpa adds it automatically. Unlike in other repositories, the author doesn't need to upload his package to Melpa. Instead,  he just tells Melpa where the package is located, and Melpa pulls in the file every few hours. When it does this "pulling" it takes the liberty of modifying the version number.

Comment: So the author's repository says `;;; Version: 0.9.0` and Melpa changes it to `;;; Version: 20130607.917`? If so, then (1) that's pretty bad, and (2) they could probably resolve this easily by making it `;;; Version: 0.9.0.20130607.917` (i.e. `original-version`.`date-time`) which should then make for a very obvious comparison against another source showing version `0.9.0`). And that would also provide an obvious way to use tags -- if the current HEAD has a tag matching the version comment, then *don't* modify the comment at all.

Comment: You're going to have to ask them about this =/ (link in my answer). I don't know why they chose this method, I just know they felt it was necessary to override the version numbers completely, not just make them unique.

Comment: At least for the `git` and `github` fetchers, the `:commit` param in the recipe can specify whatever stable branch (or tag, or SHA) is appropriate. So the recipe should only point at master if master is expected to be stable. If that's not the case for some packages, I'd recommend filing an issue and @mentioning whoever contributed the recipe.